# Matching multiple fields with elastic search query string

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search, I have data in the following format:

```
{
  "person_name" : "Abraham Benjamin deVilliers",
  "name": "Abraham",
  "office":{
     "name":"my_office"
  }
},
{
  "person_name" : "John Bradshaw",
  "name": "john",
  "office": {
     "name":"Abraham deVilliers"
  }
},
{
  "person_name" : "John Bradshaw",
  "name": "Abraham deVilliers",
  "office": {
     "name":"blabla"
  }
},
{
  "person_name" : "John Bradshaw",
  "name": "Abraham",
  "office": {
     "name":"deVilliers"
  }
},
{
  "person_name" : "Abraham",
  "name": "deVilliers",
  "office": {
     "name":"blabla"
  }
}
```

I am working on search query to match a string with three fields `person_name`, `name` and `office.name`, which should return response by checking user entered query fields as follows:

If entered query string is `Abraham deVilliers`, then it should return users having both `Abraham` and `deVilliers` as part of their `person_name` or `name` or `office.name` as below:

```
   {
      "person_name" : "Abraham Benjamin deVilliers",
      "name": "Abraham",
      "office":{
         "name":"my_office"
      }
    },
    {
      "person_name" : "John Bradshaw",
      "name": "john",
      "office": {
         "name":"Abraham deVilliers"
      }
    },
    {
      "person_name" : "John Bradshaw",
      "name": "Abraham deVilliers",
      "office": {
         "name":"blabla"
      }
    }
```

I have tried with `query_string` search query of elastic search as follows:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string":
          {   "fields": ["person_name", "name", "office.name"],
              "query": "Abraham AND deVilliers"
          }
    }
}
```

The search query returns expected result but it also returns response matching `first_name: Abraham` from `name` and  `last_name: deVilliers` from `office.name`, which i don't want.

I want to exclude below profiles from returning by the `query_string` query

```
    {
      "person_name" : "John Bradshaw",
      "name": "Abraham",
      "office": {
         "name":"deVilliers"
      }
    },
    {
      "person_name" : "Abraham",
      "name": "deVilliers",
      "office": {
         "name":"blabla"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a job for multimatch query, try something like this:

```
GET <index_name>/_search?explain=true
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "Abraham deVilliers",
      "type":       "best_fields",
      "fields":     [ "person_name", "name", "office.name" ],
      "operator":"and"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked exactly as expected.