# Elasticsearch Search : query_string on multiple fields returns unexpected results

Tags: elasticsearch, query-optimization

According to this question that is tagged as resolved :
[Matching multiple fields with elastic search query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550506/matching-multiple-fields-with-elastic-search-query-string/76023656)

It is asked why a document on which the query_string is matching through multiple fields is returned. (The query_string is matching into a combinaison of both fields instead of matching for each field).

The answer is to use `multi_match`. But what if we would need to use a query string ? For example we want to look at "(Abraham AND deVilliers) OR (Johnny)" in either person_name exlusive, or name exclusive, or office.name exclusive ?

Must we use a `should` of query_string on each field, or is it possible to use a single query_string of best_fields of multiple fields ?

The author question is interesting because it not clear regarding query_string and best_fields docs :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-best-fields

> The best_fields type is most useful when you are searching for
> multiple words best found in the same field. For instance “brown fox”
> in a single field is more meaningful than “brown” in one field and
> “fox” in the other.
>
> The best_fields type generates a match query for each field and wraps
> them in a dis_max query, to find the single best matching field.

We expect that the results "matching `first_name: Abraham` from `name` and `last_name: deVilliers` from `office.name`" should not be returned, because "best_fields generates a **match query for each field**" with the query_string "Abraham AND deVilliers"...

I would like to use a `query_string` that gonna check exclusively/individually each field of `fields` and find the best field, like the documentation says.